# Custom STS Showing ID instead of UserName as Account Name when Authenticated

Tags: 2013, administration, claims-based-auth

I have a custom STS installed on SharePoint that uses a CAC card for authentication.  I have a separate database and a custom Claims Provider I am using to authenticate users.  I am having an issue with secondary site collections where the User name is being replaced with the CAC ID instead of the Account name.  User ID (CAC ID) is the ClaimInputType.

When I am going to the top-level site collection of the claims authentication web app, Everything is working just fine.  I am authenticated, permissions are working well, and my profile is recognizing me through the claims and is getting my account name like it should.  However, when I create a new site collection, the claims is not returning my Account name and is getting my CAC ID only.  In the people picker, I can see my Account name when I search for it, but it will resolve to my ID when I select it.  When I go to my settings, the Account Name is not being set along with my email on the seconday site collections.  The top-level site collection behaves just fine.

I have seen this behavior before with ADFS, but I am unsure of where to look for it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what my issue was.  I have to create a new Profile synce because I am not using ADFS or AD to get my user profiles.  I had to create a custom sync service to load all of the profile data from my DB to the UPS.  Now that I have a custom sync, the issue has been resolved.